# With Node.js, how can I make two HTTP GET requests and combine the resulting data and send it back to a user?

Tags: node.js

Say I have the following code that sends back json data (that I get from example.com first) back to a user that made a post request

```
app.post('/riot', function(request, response) {
    var riotAPI = https.get("https://example.com", function(riotResponse){
        var body = "";  
        riotResponse.on('data', function(chunk){
            body+= chunk;
        });
        riotResponse.on('end', function(){
            response.type('json');
            response.end(body);     
        });
    });
});
```

What do I do if I want to get more data from a different website and send json data from both website back to user? I am using express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do this. I would suggest using the [request npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) instead of calling https directly. With `request` you can simply pass in callback which is called when a request finishes, so no need to deal with chunks of data.

If you take this approach then you can just use something like [async.parallel()](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) to run both requests in parallel. `async.parallel` takes one callback that is called when all of its async functions have finished.. and that is where you would send your response.